# Mysql - Query GroupBy not returning correct time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm having a huge issue with the sql query below , basically i want to group the table by date "Y-m-d" , find the minimum value for that group and return the time it occurred .

However it keeps returning time = 00:00:00 and i have no idea what is wrong . Any help would be highly appreciated .

**e.g : for the first result , it correctly calculated the minimum price for that group but the time was 04:00:00 , but it still returned 00:00:00**

*Based on the id returned , it seems its returning the date for the first element of that group - not the actual date of the minimum price occurring.*

```
Select val_date 
     , id
     , MIN(average_price) AS min_value 
  from tableY
 GROUP 
    BY Month(val_date) 
     , Year(val_date) 
     , Day(val_date);
```

Table :

[image: sql]

Result :

```
[{"val_date":"2017-01-01 00:00:00","id":1,"min_value":964.33},
{"val_date":"2017-01-02 00:00:00","id":25,"min_value":998.24},
{"val_date":"2017-01-03 00:00:00","id":49,"min_value":1016.4},
{"val_date":"2017-01-04 00:00:00","id":73,"min_value":1034.02}
```

**Tried :**

```
Select val_date 
     , id
     , MIN(average_price) AS min_value 
  from tableY
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(val_date,'%m') 
     , DATE_FORMAT(val_date,'%Y') 
     , DATE_FORMAT(val_date,'%d';
```

Still returns 00:00:00 for all results

Comment: The min function will return the lowest value for that column in the group. That is independant of the values returned for other columns. You need to get the ID of the row with the minimum value in order to get the related values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need  the row values for min value by date(val_date) you could use in subselect  as

```
  select val_date, id, average_price as min_value, 
  from tableY
  where ( val_date, average_price) in (
     select 
            date(val_date) 
          , MIN(average_price) 
      from tableY 
      group by date(val_date) 
  )
```

or using join

```
select a.val_date, a.id, a.average_price as min_value, 
from tableY a
inner join (
      select 
            date(val_date)   as date_val_date
          , MIN(average_price)  min_price
      from tableY 
      group by date(val_date) 
) t on date(a.val_date ) = t.date_val_date and a.average_price = t.min_price
```

Comment: Thanks . The first one is not working but the join works perfect .